# How should I notate this function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, notation

My apologies for the vague, non-descript title, I couldn't come up with a concise way to describe what I mean.

Basically, I have a sequence $A$ such that $\forall \;x \in A: x \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let's take $n = 6$ as an example. $A$ could look like this, for example:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ 3 ║ 1 ║ 4 ║ 4 ║ 5 ║ 1 ║ 6 ║ 2 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Now, I want to have a function that takes in a sequence $X$ and an index $i$ and returns the number of times that $X_{i}$ has appeared in $X$ up until $i$. An example would probably help here.

Let's say that our index is $4$ and we're using sequence $A$. We look at what's in the fourth place in $A$; it's the number 4. Then, starting from the beginning of the sequence, we check every item in the sequence to see if it equals 4. However, once we reach the $i$-th element, we stop.

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ 3 ║ 1 ║ 4 ║ 4 ║ 5 ║ 1 ║ 6 ║ 2 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
          ^   ^    we don't even bother 
          |   |    checking all of these
```

In this case, the function would return 2.

Is there any way that I could notate this? It doesn't even have to be compact or particularly legible, I just need a way to describe what I'm talking about mathematically.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you calculating a histogram for the sequence elements until the index?

Comment: @NeitherNor The short of it is: no, The long of it: I was bored in class one day and decided to generate some random numbers and assign them a colour. Then I counted up each occurrence of the colours as described in the post above and noticed that after doing it once, the 'function' became cyclic with order two; it repeated itself. So I wanted to get a better understanding of why this happens.

Comment: Just name the function and describe the function exactly as you have here... This function is hardly ever if ever at all used in mathematics so there won't be an official name or choice of notation for it.  This sounds more like something out of programming in which case just use pseudocode or actual code to notate it...

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Oh my word, why didn't I think of that? Thank you! Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @JMoravitz I thought of that, but I feel like pseudocode requires a bit more knowledge than just mathematics.

Comment: No, I am not asking what you want to do, but what you are doing. Please explain why this is not a histogram in your opinion. You could then call it $H_i(x)$ or something. If your sequence is long enough, why not normalize the number you get by $i$ to get a nice conditional probability $P(X_j=X_i|j\leq i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ X_i=\text{ cardinality of }\{A_k=A_i \vert k\le i\}$$

Comment: I was trying to copy & paste my comment but accidentally deleted it instead.